# Array pointer has not hold expected value

Tags: c, pointers

I declared an array a = {1,2,3} and then take a pointer int *p = a
Now p, a, &a[0] should have the same value. But when I use a for loop to print the array a, the initial value of p showing (a+4) . Code:

```
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int *p = a;

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("&a[0]=%p p=%p a=%p p=%d\n", &a[0], p, a, *p++);
}
```

Output:

```
&a[0]=0061FF0C p=0061FF10 a=0061FF0C *p=1

&a[0]=0061FF0C p=0061FF14 a=0061FF0C *p=2

&a[0]=0061FF0C p=0061FF18 a=0061FF0C *p=3
```

Here, in first line of the output why p is not equal to 0061FF0C ?

Comment: Because you are incrementing your pointer in the final "*p++"

Comment: got it. thank you..